# How can I fix this error from the manifest file in xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a widget using [this tutorial](https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/).
I've done everything step by step according to the instructions.
The following errors occur like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkuYS.jpg) and I don't know what's going on.

> Failed processing manifest.
> Resource `xml/appwidgetprovider` (aka enfoglobe.courts.mobile:xml/appwidgetprovider) not found.

> This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file.

Anyone has any ideas?

Here is a [screenshot of the Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xHz4.png).

Comment: Please don't post errors and code as images. Use the code blocks. Also you need to look in the compiled manifest in the obj/Debug/android folder after attempting to build, otherwise you won't get the full manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that you are missing the file `xml/appwidgetprovider`.

Did you add it to Resources/xml/appwidgetprovider.xml?

If you did, remember to set the correct build action on it as `AndroidResource` otherwise it will not be picked up.

Comment: Hello,
I implemented this code https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/ to show the widget. After pressing the widget, my mobile application starts. I would like to implement the so-called badge count on the widget (number of notifications on the icon). Is there any library that would help me do this in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: have you seen this? https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=badge+count&docid=607989815340971120&mid=55647977E4C9F8B06A0455647977E4C9F8B06A04&view=detail&FORM=VIRE